# How to show text in original format from database?

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-blade

I have a text, recorded in db as 'text'. In query it looks as it was - with all whitespaces.
But when I'm trying to output this text using {{$text}} in view - text loses all whitespaces and become jammed, like it was written all in one string.
I've tried to use `Str::of($text)->toHtmlString();` but it throws `Method Illuminate\Support\Stringable::toHtmlString does not exist`

Comment: Please post example data of how the text/string looks in your database as well as how it looks in your blade file (which you could/should also post)

Answer (score 0):

If your data at '$text' something like this

> This example data

You can try this {!! $text !!} at your view